# Disable touchpad when typing

Tags: shell, touchpad

I can't run "syndaemon" because of my touchpad device.

My `xinput -list` output

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 Camera                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: first thing I did when got a laptop is disable the touchpad completely better in bios... I only choose laptop with trackpoint or desktop. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw my idea is make a shell script for enable and disable the touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the command "synclient"

```
#synclient TouchPadOff=1
#synclient TouchPadOff=0
```

*TouchPadOff=1* to disable touch pad.
*TouchPadOff=0* to enable touch pad.

Then, I have added these two commands in hotkeys to make enable and disable tasks easy.
It works fine.